# Load Possession plugin using NvChad

Tags: neovim, neovim-plugin

I am trying to load [Possession](https://github.com/jedrzejboczar/possession.nvim?tab=readme-ov-file) plugin for NvChad. I have tried following [this](https://docs.rockylinux.org/books/nvchad/plugins/) guide and I have read the [docs](https://nvchad.com/docs/config/plugins/). When doing `:Lazy` and after `S-I` to install the package, it seems to be present but when I try to use `:PossessionSave` I get `E492: Not an editor command`. I am new to both `nvim` and `NvChad` and I feel I am missing something quite obvious. Any help appreciated.

My `custom/plugins.lua` looks like this:

```
{
   'jedrzejboczar/possession.nvim',
}
```

because `plenary.nvim` is installed by default.

I have tried:

```
{
   'jedrzejboczar/possession.nvim',
   config = function()
      require('possession').setup()
   end,
}
```

but it doesn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 0):

Quite embarrassing but it was a very simple solution:

```
{
   'jedrzejboczar/possession.nvim',
   cmd ={"SSave", "SLoad", "SShow"}
   config = function()
      require('possession').setup {
      save = "SSave",
      load = "SLoad",
      show = "SShow",
   }
   end,
}
```

That is, omit `()` after `.setup`; you MUST include one of `ft`, `cmd`, `keys`, `event` if you want the plugin to lazy load else you MUST include `lazy=false`. Or at least that's how it seems to me. I have changed the default commands.